# Keywords spotting: hypotesis is null until it is exactly one of the keyword you are looking for

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I'm using `onPartialResult` method to look if the `hypotesis` is one of the keyword I'm interested in and it works well.

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPartialResult");

    if (hypothesis == null) {
        return;
    }

    String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();

    String wordWithProb = "";
    String mostProbableWord = "";
    int probability = -10000;

    if (text.contains("|")) {
        for (Segment seg : recognizer.getDecoder().seg()) {
            wordWithProb += "|" + seg.getWord() + " " + seg.getProb() + "|";
            if (seg.getProb() > probability)
                mostProbableWord = seg.getWord().trim();
        }
    }
    else
        mostProbableWord = text.trim();

    Log.i(TAG, "onPartialResults: " + mostProbableWord);

    String recognizedCommand = "Please repeat";
    if (mostProbableWord.equals("one")) {
       //do something...
    } else if (mostProbableWord.equals("two")) {
       //do something...
    } else if (mostProbableWord.equals("three")) {
       //do something...
    } 

    //text to speech
    speak(recognizedCommand);

    startListening(KWS_SEARCH);
}
```

Now **I would like to handle the case where a user say something and it is not recognized as a keyword; in this case the hypotesis in the `onPartialResult` method is always `null`: is this expected?** I was expecting a not null hypotesis here... 
Considering that `onPartialResult` method is automatically called by pocketsphinx consinuously (also when there isn't any sound in the air) I cannot use the `null` hypothesis as my driving condition.
Moreover there is a text to speech after every recognition and so the recognition listener restart has to be handled carefully: recognizer must not be listening while text to speech is ongoing...
I tried some solution with `onEndOfSpeech` but none was good until now...
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in this case the hypotesis in the onPartialResult method is always null: is this expected?

Yes

> Moreover there is a text to speech after every recognition and so the recognition listener restart has to be handled carefully: recognizer must not be listening while text to speech is ongoing

Correct

Comment: Hello @Nikolay, sometimes (rarely) it happens also that a not null hypothesis is generated and this is not matching a keyword. This happens when the speech is very similar to a keyword... Anyway...  How can I handle the case where a user say something and it is not recognized as a keyword? Is onEndOfSpeech the solution? Is there a way to distinguish between noise and speech at least?

Comment: There is no solution to distinguish between noise and speech yet, you have to implement it yourself.